# Really slow login with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm working on an old site ad the login function takes forever. I'm trying to get to the bottom of this only im unsure whats causing it.

The login function uses AJAX.

**AJAX**

```
$password = md5($_POST['thepassword']);
$user = $_POST['theusername'];

$loginVar = $usersClass->login($user, $password);

if(is_array($loginVar))
{
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $loginVar; 
    @session_regenerate_id(true);

    print "success";

}else{
    print "Whoops, something went wrong! Try again.";
}
```

**PHP Class**

```
public function login($username, $password)
{

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`active` from `$this->usersTable` WHERE 
        `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND 
        `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");

    if($rs) {
        $row = @mysql_fetch_object($rs);

            return $this->userInfo($row->id);

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a lot (millions) of users and no indexes? Nothing inherently slow about this code.

Comment: If that is the case, a composite index on `username,password` could make a very big difference.

Comment: As @MichaelBerkowski suggests, have you checked if the DB is optimized? Run a sample `username` and `password` query directly and see how long it takes.

Comment: You can also add a `LIMIT 1` to the query. It could potentially improve performance depending on how your indices are setup. It certainly won't make it worse.

Comment: I have about 8 thousand members and no I dont have an index, when I build the site I didnt anticipate it to recieve many signups, plus I was still learning (and still am) PHP

Comment: what does the method userInfo do? also, have you tried the query directly in mysql both with explain and without?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have no index, I will suggest adding a composite index over `username` and `password`:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_user_pass` ON `user_table` (`username`, `password`)
```

Review the [MySQL `CREATE INDEX` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for full details.

As I mentioned in the comment thread, there is nothing inherently slow about your code as it is.

I will note some things to be aware of (and I suspect you know this since you have been an SO member for a long time). It is recommended to remove the `@` error suppression operators. You do have error checking on `$rs` already, so there's no need for additional suppression here.

```
$row = @mysql_fetch_object($rs);
//----^^
```

And I know you are already familiar with PDO and prepared statements from other questions, so no need to go into that...

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski, I've added the index now, however it's not made much difference

Comment: @Liam Failing that, you ought to look at your browser's network console while the AJAX request is performed. There could be DNS lookup problems (though I doubt it). If you created a form which directly posted the user/pass would that be slow as well?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems ike everything is ok with the code itself, it could be the server that is having troubles and it slows script down.
Also, `$password = md5($_POST['thepassword']); $user = $_POST['theusername'];` :
Don't use md5 hashing anymore, instead go for sha2 and for the user, please use mysql_real_escape_string at least for security around it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using PDO or mysql_fetch_assoc, according to PHP.net this function is slightly slower then mysql_fetch_assoc,

> Speed-wise, the function is identical to mysql_fetch_array(), and
>   almost as quick as mysql_fetch_row() (the difference is insignificant).

1. Echo is slightly faster then print;

But even if you're code has better performance I doubt it has something to do with you're code. I think the database is a bit slow, are you using INNODB with an index in the fiels you're searching? This is a lot faster..

Answer (score 0):

First as said in the comments, you should check if your table has indexes. For that, you can find out if it's the case by running this query :

`` EXPLAIN SELECT id, active FROM [users_tables] WHERE `username` = '[username]' AND `password` = '[password]' ``

(replace [...] by the rights values)

Then, I think you should avoid using @ in front of session_generate_id and mysql_fetch_object.

Also, check the function userInfo if it's not doing another MySQL request,  if you've a busy table it's better to get all data once you check the login password than in two times.

Finally, change your table (caution with this process, you can loose data) from MyISAM to InnoDB, as last one has a lock per row and MyISAM a lock per table.